# Array value as a condition

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, if-statement

I have an array of integers called `test` containing 7 elements,I want to write an if statement to check if the 6 first values of the array are equal to a certain collection of values,what I tried was:

```
if (test == {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0} ) {
//statement(s)
}
```

However,the line containing the condition gives me an **"expected an expression error"**,what am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably wanted [`std::equal`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal).

Comment: If you make `test` a `std::vector<int>` you could do `if(test == std::vector{1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}) { }`

Comment: @TedLyngmo The line contaning the condition gives me an "argument list for class template "std::array" is missing" error,any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++17 versions using deduction guides:

`std::array`

```
std::array test{1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0};

if(test == std::array{1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}) {
    std::cout << "equal\n";
}
```

`std::vector`

```
std::vector test{1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0};

if(test == std::vector{1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}) {
    std::cout << "equal\n";
}
```

Comment: Both lines containing the conditions give me "argument list for class template "std::array" is missing" and "argument list for class template "std::vector" is missing" errors respectively,even though both the vector and array headers are included.

Comment: @TheRiser It only works in C++17 and later so you need to select the C++17 standard in Visual Studio, otherwise it'll use C++14. Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/c2Xwf3

Comment: I apologize for the late reply,but I wasn't able to declare the array and the vector the way you did even after switching to C++17 as I always end up with a *"no instance of constructor "..." matches the argument list"* error,the only thing accepted by the compiler is the line: `std::vector <int> test{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };` and even then the line containing the condition still gives me a *"no instance of constructor "std::vector" matches the argument list"* error.

Comment: @TheRiser You must use an old version of Visual Studio with poor C++17 support. In VS2019 this is absolutely no problem.

Comment: I'm using VS2017 so that must be the problem,however since I know this solution works I'll find find a way to make it work,thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you use `std::array` you can simply rely on `operator==`

```
  std::array<int, 7> a1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
  std::array<int, 7> a2 = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
  std::cout << "a1 == a1 " << (a1 == a1) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "a1 == a2 " << (a1 == a2) << std::endl;
```

However, if for some reason you need to use C-style array, then you can use `std::memcmp`, which will compare the arrays byte by byte:

```
  int ca1[7] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
  int ca2[7] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
  std::cout << "ca1 == ca1 " << (std::memcmp(ca1, ca1, sizeof(ca1)) == 0) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "ca1 == ca2 " << (std::memcmp(ca1, ca2, sizeof(ca1)) == 0) << std::endl;
```

Note that you need to compare the `std::memcmpy` result with 0, which means that they are equal. [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcmp) However, in this approach you should first check if the dimensions are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it (if your `test` is an `std::array`):

```
#include <algorithm>

...

std::vector<int> v({1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0});
if( (v.size()==test.size()) && std::equal(test.begin(), test.end(), v.begin()) ) {
// statement(s)
}
```

or

```
#include <algorithm>

...

std::vector<int> v({1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0});
if( std::equal(test.begin(), test.end(), v.begin(), v.end()) ) {
// statement(s)
}
```

Comment: 3rd argument of `std::equal` is also Iterator. Did you mean `std::vector<int>({1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}).begin()` ? Also this approach might give incorrect results or Undefined Behavior is `test.size()` is not equal to the number of elements in the initializer list.

Comment: @pptaszni fixed. Thanks.